# django show one field of a form in custom layout and css

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a form like below:

```
class IdentifyForm(BaseModelForm):
    sms_code = forms.CharField(label=u'sms verification code')
    class Meta:
        model = Member
        fields = ('realname', 'mobile', 'openid',)
        widgets = {
            'openid': HiddenInput(),
        }
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(IdentifyForm, self).clean()
        openid = cleaned_data.get('openid')
        mobile = cleaned_data.get('mobile')
        realname = cleaned_data.get('realname')
        sms_code = cleaned_data.get('sms_code')

        if openid and sms_code:
            if str(sms_code) != cache.get('smscode:'+openid):
                raise forms.ValidationError(u'sms verification code error')

        return cleaned_data
```

I want to make the sms_code `input` has half width of other fields, and put a send button right to it.And some javascript code in page to manipulate this button and sms_code field

for now ,I have to do like below:

```
{% if form.realname.errors %}
    <div class="error-msg">
        {{ form.realname.errors|striptags }}
    </div>
{% endif %}
<div class="form-line">
    {{ form.realname }}
</div>

{% if form.mobile.errors %}
    <div class="error-msg">
        {{ form.mobile.errors|striptags }}
    </div>
{% endif %}
<div class="form-line">
    {{ form.mobile }}
</div>

{% if form.sms_code.errors %}
    <div class="error-msg">
        {{ form.sms_code.errors|striptags }}
    </div>
{% endif %}
<div class="form-line">
    {{ form.sms_code }}
    <a class="sms_btn">
        <span class="disable">&nbsp;resend after <i></i> second</span>
        &nbsp;
        <span class="normal">send sms code</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

But I want to render such form in a more common way such as :

```
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}

    <div class="form-line">
        <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.label }}</label>&nbsp;
        {% if field.errors %}
            <span class="error-msg">
                {{ field.errors|striptags }}
            </span>
        {% endif %}
        {{ field }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

because there is no guarantee that `IdentifyForm` would not require more field in future.It is good to separate frontend and backend.Frontend needn't know which field should be display.But I have no idea how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a good opportunity to look at [django-crispy-forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). It lets you define helpers and layouts directly in the `Form` class, and comes with some default template plugins for things like bootstrap. See the example from the docs:

```
class ExampleForm(forms.Form):
    [...]
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExampleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Fieldset(
                'first arg is the legend of the fieldset',
                'like_website',
                'favorite_number',
                'favorite_color',
                'favorite_food',
                'notes'
            ),
            ButtonHolder(
                Submit('submit', 'Submit', css_class='button white')
            )
        )
```

And then your template:

```
{% crispy myform %}
```

Answer (score 0):

**In form defination:**

```
class IdentifyForm(BaseModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['sms_code'].widget.attrs.update({'class' : 'prepend_to_widget'})
```

**In template or a global js file:**

```
<script>
    $(".prepend_to_widget").prepend('<a class="sms_btn">
        <span class="disable">&nbsp;resend after <i></i> second</span>
        &nbsp;
        <span class="normal">send sms code</span>
    </a>');
</script>
```

**Note:** You need jquery to to this. If you don't use jquery u may do this with pure javascript or with a help of another javascript libray.